# How to access 16-bit Array using base+displacement

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, 32-bit, gnu-assembler

I am having trouble accessing 16-bit array elements using base+displacement method.

Below is the code:

```
.section .data
t1:
.int 10, 15, 25
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
   movl $t1, %ecx
   movl (%ecx), %edx # this gets 10 in edx
   movl 2(%ecx), %ebx # this does not get 15 in ebx
   movl $1, %eax
   int $0x80
```

How do i access t1[1...] elements.

Comment: `.int` with x86 targets (64-bit or 32-bit) is 4 bytes I believe. Maybe you'll want `.word`. After you fix that - If you want to mov a 16-bit value to a register use a 16-bit register. Instead of _ECX_ as the destination use _CX_ (for example)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I just checked with `echo '.int 0x90909090' > foo.S` / assemble / disassemble to 4 NOPs, not 2, so you're right, the OP has `.word 10, 0, 15, 0, 25, 0`

Comment: As it should @PeterCordes as I'm pretty sure the GNU assembler documentation documents (for x86 targets) `.int` being synonymous with `.long` and both being 32-bits. `.word` is defined as 16-bit.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: It's what I thought, too, but it was faster to check than to google up the docs, both under 1 minute :P  I wasn't 100% sure because I know gcc uses `.long` for 32-bit chunks of static data on x86.

Comment: @MichaelPetch mentioned using CX instead of ECX, but actually you still want 32-bit ECX for the pointer, and 16-bit registers for the data.  Or do something like `movzwl 2(%ecx), %ebx` for a zero-extending load of 16 bits from memory, putting the result in a full 32-bit register where you can use it normally.  Unlike `movw 2(%ecx), %dx`  which leaves garbage in the high 2 bytes of EDX.